# DC to DC power conversion

Tags: power-supply, power, amplifier, dc-dc-converter

I want to supply power to three circuits which require 12V, 12V and 24V from a single 12V 2 ampere rated power adapter.

Two circuits are **TDA2030** left and right stereo amplifiers each with a 5W speaker, and one is a **TDA2050** amplifier for a 20W subwoofer.

I don't want to supply power to these separately, and I don't have a transformer either just have a 12V 2 ampere rated DC power adapter.

Please suggest me the best efficient way for this such that sound quality can't be negotiated.

Note: Can include voltage regulators or DC to DC step-up converters, but please try to suggest it cost-efficient if possible.

**Edit:** All speakers have an impedance of 8ohms and working perfectly when played by the separate power supply.
I am satisfied with the Amplifier and sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably already know, your power supply is grossly under powered if you want maximum volume. At low volume, I am not sure what benefit the subwoofer will have, so you can simply run the two TDA2030 with the 12V supply you have. The TDA2050 will also run on 12V if you want to experiment, but sound volume and quality will probably be horrible.

Three options for power supply:

1. 24V 3A to run everything (since TDA2030 can tolerate 24V). (100W 24V SMPS are readily available everywhere)
2. one 12V 2.5A for the two TDA2030 and one 24V 1.5A for the TDA2050
3. 12-6-0-6-12 or some other combination of transformers to obtain dual ±15 (and if required ±6V supply). Most complicated but *may* give best sound quality if designed properly.

You will also need lot of bulk capacitors for running audio amplifiers since the peak current will exceed capacity of the power supply. The power supply may also need to be protected against reverse discharge by the capacitors. Power chokes may also need to be used to prevent SMPS shutdown due to overcurrent and to prolong bulk capacitor life. High current power supplies are not trivial to design.

Answer (score 2):

> Please suggest me the best efficient way for this such that sound quality can't be negotiated.

If sound quality is non-negotiable, you definitely picked the completely wrong amplifier. Like, completely, totally, the wrong device. This is a obsolete amplifier for cheap devices. It's utterly bad, acoustically.

> Is 18V sufficient?

Please finally get around to *really* reading the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000128.pdf) whenever you have a question about what the TDA2030 can do. No magic involved. Not even much engineering.

Look at figure 4 (on page 5). It clearly says you need more voltage.

No.

This is the wrong amplifier for your job.

Let's calculate what you need in power supply for a perfect, does-not-even-exist 100% efficient amplifier. Your TDA2030 restricts your load to no less than 4Ω, so I'll assume that's your subwoofer's impedance.

To get 20W of power \$P\$ out of that:

$$P=U\cdot I=U\cdot\frac UR = \frac{U^2}R\implies U = \sqrt{PR}= \sqrt{80}\,\text V\approx 9\,\text{V}\text.$$

That requires 100% efficiency, as said. Your TDA2030 is **very** far away from that:  With **acceptable** (not: good. Even 0.5% THD is barely acceptable.) acoustic performance, your TDA2030 achieves maybe 40% efficiency. That means you need to cool away 60% of input input power, in other words, your 20W subwoofer amplifier makes as much heat as a 30W light bulb. That is much. Building a cooler for that is expensive and complicated.

> Actually, 2 circuits are TDA2030 Left and Right stereo Amplifier each with a 5W speaker. And one is TDA2050 Amplifier for 20W subwoofer.

That's 30 W in output power, and since the TDA2030 is so inefficient, you need about 70 W in supplied power. Your power supply offers 24 W. **this cand't work!**

The TDA2030 is a terrible choice. Get a different amplifier. You simply picked the wrong component for your job. *It doesn't matter whether it's the only thing you've got lying around. If you have a fish lying around, you can still not fell a tree with a fish. Get a different amplifier.*

Vishal, honestly, this is a bad approach: You're trying to build a high-power switch mode power supply (relatively complex and expensive) to power an inefficient class-AB amplifier. Stop it. If you were to hand in that design to any design review, you'd be getting a "completely missed the point" review.

Drop the TDA2030. Get a class-D amplifier IC. With a bit of luck, one of the many companies that manufacture them will send you a free sample (Indraneel says at least TI does!). For your 5W speakers, get a stereo amplifier. I think the [PAM8320](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/PAM8320) mono amplifier will make you happy for your subwoofer. But there's also Stereo+bass combination ICs.

Comment: If he's going to get samples, please suggest something that is 2.1 channels, or at least 2 channels. Texas Instruments ships samples readily to India.... I don't know about diodes inc.

Comment: @Indraneel done. Hopefully this really convinces Vishal; he's been trying to build anything decent out of the TDA2030 for about 10 questions now, and he's always getting an "oh, that's the wrong IC". Maybe, one day he'll actually see he's beating a dead horse.

Comment: Okay, TDA2030 is not perfect. But, I am just a casual creator so I don't mind using it. Secondly, all speakers are 8 ohms and I am using TDA2050 for subwoofer which can power 20W easily as mentioned in the datasheet.

Comment: no, it's not "Not perfect": it's the **wrong** amplifier for your application. I don't know how much more explicit I can say it: It's **wrong**. Use a **different** amplifier.

Comment: I mean I made this ridiculous fish analogy. It's a stupid analogy, but I feel this is by now the level we're at, since you keep on trying to make the TDA2030 do something it can't. So, for your convenience, let me copy it again: *it doesn't matter whether it's the only thing you've got lying around. If you have a fish lying around, you can still not fell a tree with a fish. Get a different amplifier.*

Comment: Okay, I got your point.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I can't blame him. The TDA2030 is readily available here at every shop for less than 25 cents each. I wanted to make one too... but chose to simply use earphones instead... cheap, nothing to make and great sound quality, not to mention privacy, portability, and zero irritation for the neighborhood...

Comment: @indraneel Yes, you are correct. And it's sound better than a ₹500 speaker set. Perfect for projects ✌️

Comment: @Vishal but a headphone is not a 5W speaker. And what Indrareel very nicely says is: you're using the wrong amplifier for your job, because you don't see the difference between a speaker and a headphone.

Comment: @Vishal long time back (I think 1990s) there was circuit of active crossover power amplifier in electronics for you magazine. It used two TDA2002 per channel, one for woofer, one for tweeter. the active crossover at the input had two stage amplifier using transistors (which can probably be replaced with a ne5532 or similar). I lined a speaker box with thick layer of cotton and a cotton cloth to keep it in place with small nails. Then adjusted the active crossover feedback resistors and capacitors by listening to output. I don't think I have heard such excellent sound again in my life.

Comment: @Vishal and quality sound requires quality speakers, run at low volume (not the speaker whose photo u posted in the other thread). Get a 8 inch woofer and a 2.5 inch tweeter, and spend some time estimating their frequency and volume response (catch 22: u will need a TDA2030 for that... using ur smartphone as a signal generator). Then create a crossover circuit to handle it.

Comment: @Indraneel nice! I'll allow myself to point, however, out that if Vishal goes out and buys new speakers, he might also want to go out and buy a not-ancient amplifier IC to drive these, because that makes his life easier, and will indeed lead to better sound quality at lower effort.

Answer (score 1):

12V 2A is 24W for your supply.

You want to supply 30W of audio output which will need about 60W of supply.

You need to rethink your power supply solution getting good audio will not come from a cheap supply. A transformer giving the correct output voltages will be needed plus rectifiers, filters, regulators and more filters if you cannot negotiate sound quality.

Comment: Is 18V sufficient?

Comment: What if I use a DC to DC set-up converter for this?? Can I get more power through that??

Comment: @Vishal you can't get more power by converting voltage. power is energy per unit time. the amount u get will always be less than what u put in (depending on efficiency of supply/converter)

Comment: Okay, so converting 12V to 24V doesn't step up current and power. Thankyou for clarification. One more que, what is expected output current if I step up 12V 2Amp to 24V, current will increase or decrease in output or remains same?

Comment: @Vishal the TDA2030 datasheet. Read it. It's answered in a prominent figure there. But, no matter what you do, the TDA2030 *can't* drive 20W with acceptable audio quality. "10% THD" is *terrible* sound.

Comment: @Marcus plz read que again. I am using TDA2050 for 20W woofer not TDA2030

Comment: @Vishal that really doesn't change anything about the impossibility to generate power out of nowhere, and the TDA2050 is nearly as bad as the TDA2030. I mean, again, *datasheet*. The same figures, even, and the curves don't look much better.

Comment: @Vishal If you're going to ask questions like "what is expected output current if I step up 12V 2Amp to 24V, current will increase or decrease" .... then I have to strongly say that "please don't kill yourself trying to fiddle with power supplies". You need to go through a basic hobby electronics course first. At least finish volume 1 at the allaboutcircuits site before u start to hurt yourself trying to build anything at all. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/

Comment: @indraneel Thank you, but I just have a doubt regarding step-up converters. I am using them for the first time.

Comment: @Vishal the nature of your doubt, as Indrareel correctly points out, shows you're missing a basic understanding of electricity. You don't understand how much you don't understand.